# Magento product list by tags shows titles in wrong language

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento store setup in 2 languages (EN and RU) and I haven't modified any backend code for the page where it displays a list of products by tagId.

For tags in russian, the whole page displays in russian, except the titles of the products in the list, which, for some reason, are still displayed in English. The products in question have translations for both languages.

I've tried setting storeId in core /Mage/Tag/Model/Tag.php and /Mage/Tag/Model/Block/Product/List.php, but with no luck and the default code sets the store Id in /Mage/Tag/Model/Block/Product/Result.php like this:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if(is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
        $this->_productCollection = $tagModel->getEntityCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addTagFilter($this->getTag()->getId())
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setActiveFilter();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection(
            $this->_productCollection
        );
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

I've searched for this issue everywhere, but can't find any similar case anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by debugging my /app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml. I realized that if I get product name just after "foreach" collection it was OK but then some lines after it wasn't.

Problem was with a custom function that loaded media_gallery attribute:

```
$product->load('media_gallery')
```

I solved changing it into:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
```

I hope it helps you or at least you could debug your list.phtml and get where the product loses its attributes.